# Area of influence with CartoDB

Tags: postgis, carto, sql, buffer, markers

I am working on a city transport map, and for fun (and practice) I try to make an area of influence of transport station. But, whatever I try, something gets wrong. So two questions.

1 - How can I fix marker size with distance? I have metro, tram and bus stations. Each one has a different area size (1km, 750 ans 500m), that I have included in the datasheet already.

2- How can I fix marker size whatever the zoom is, and automatically speaking (that means I don't have to write in CSS code for each zoom level)?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a marker you can generate a `buffer`, setting each category (metro, tam and bus) to a numeric field (1000, 750 and 500). Then run the following queries:

```
SELECT
  cartodb_id,
  ST_Transform(
    ST_Buffer(the_geom::geography, 1000)::geometry
    ,3857
  ) AS the_geom_webmercator
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  field_name ilike 'metro';

SELECT
  cartodb_id,
  ST_Transform(
    ST_Buffer(the_geom::geography, 750)::geometry
    ,3857
  ) AS the_geom_webmercator
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  field_name ilike 'tram';

SELECT
  cartodb_id,
  ST_Transform(
    ST_Buffer(the_geom::geography, 500)::geometry
    ,3857
  ) AS the_geom_webmercator
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  field_name ilike 'bus';
```

Yo can create a dataset for every subquery or just one. It's up to you. And if you like coding in SQL and using PostGIS functions, check out [this tutorial](http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/sql-postgis/postgis-in-cartodb/) for more details.

Comment: Hi !

Thanks a lot for the code and the link. I really appreciate.

However, I put your code in the SQL query, change table_name and field_name with the correct column name, but CartoDB does not want to apply it. 

I have «operator does not exist:integer~~* integer» or «error syntax at or near ";"». My knowledge in SQL is rusty, I will try some other stuff, but everything looks like the example on the academy page...

Comment: Try to run the queries one by one. And then create a dataset from query. You will be able to merge them later. I highly recommend you to check the tutorial I have commented in my answer, it will improve your SQL and PostGIS skills.